# Cannot set data to MPAndroidChart from outside of onCreate

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I´m trying to add a MPAndroidChart to my project, and everything was working fine when adding declaration and initialisation of the chart to the main activity. The problem comes when I start extracting the UI Logic into a different class: I only can set the data to the chart when the reference to the view class is a local variable, but when it becomes a property the data is not set.

One of the strangest things I found is that when the View class is a property, if I create a local variable in the onCreate and assign to it the View class field, then the data is set correctly.

Working implementation of the activity:

```
class MarketPriceActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val mMarketPriceViewMvc = MarketPriceViewMvcImpl(layoutInflater, null)
        setContentView(mMarketPriceViewMvc.rootView)

        mMarketPriceViewMvc.setData(getValues())

    }
    fun getValues() : List<Entry> {
        val values = mutableListOf<Entry>()
        values.add(Entry(1.0.toFloat(), 11397.80166666666.toFloat()))
        values.add(Entry(2.0.toFloat(), 11144.38916666667.toFloat()))
        values.add(Entry(3.0.toFloat(), 10450.813333333334.toFloat()))
        values.add(Entry(4.0.toFloat(), 9988.947499999998.toFloat()))
        values.add(Entry(5.0.toFloat(), 10230.733333333332.toFloat()))
        return values
    }
}
```

Not working implementation of the activity:

```
class MarketPriceActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val marketPriceViewMvcImpl: MarketPriceViewMvcImpl
        get() {
            return MarketPriceViewMvcImpl(layoutInflater, null)
        }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(marketPriceViewMvcImpl.rootView)

        marketPriceViewMvcImpl.setData(getValues())

    }
    fun getValues() : List<Entry> {
        val values = mutableListOf<Entry>()
        values.add(Entry(1.0.toFloat(), 11397.80166666666.toFloat()))
        values.add(Entry(2.0.toFloat(), 11144.38916666667.toFloat()))
        values.add(Entry(3.0.toFloat(), 10450.813333333334.toFloat()))
        values.add(Entry(4.0.toFloat(), 9988.947499999998.toFloat()))
        values.add(Entry(5.0.toFloat(), 10230.733333333332.toFloat()))
        return values
    }
}
```

Implementation of MarketPriceViewMvcImpl:

```
class MarketPriceViewMvcImpl(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup?) : BaseViewMvc() {

    private val mTxtCurrentPrice: TextView
    private val mTxtCurrentDate: TextView
    private val mChart: LineChart

    init {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_market_price, parent, false)

        mTxtCurrentPrice = findViewById(R.id.txt_current_price)
        mTxtCurrentDate = findViewById(R.id.txt_current_date)

        mChart = findViewById(R.id.chart)
        styleChart()

    }

    fun setData(values: List<Entry>) {
        var dataSet: LineDataSet
        if(mChart.data != null && mChart.data.dataSetCount > 0) {
            dataSet = mChart.data.getDataSetByIndex(0) as LineDataSet
            dataSet.values = values
            mChart.data.notifyDataChanged()
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        else {
            dataSet = LineDataSet(values, "Bitcoin")

            styleDataSet(dataSet)

            mChart.data = LineData(dataSet)
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is in charge of styling the general aspects of the chart
     */
    private fun styleChart() {

        // General Chart Style
        mChart.setTouchEnabled(true)
        mChart.setPinchZoom(true)

        mChart.setBackgroundColor(rootView!!.resources.getColor(R.color.backgroundColor))
        mChart.legend.isEnabled = false
        mChart.description.isEnabled = false

        // Axis
        mChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false

        val xAxis = mChart.xAxis
        xAxis.textColor = Color.WHITE
        xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM

        val yAxis = mChart.axisLeft
        yAxis.textColor = Color.WHITE

    }

    /**
     * This method is in charge of styling the general aspects of a given DataSet
     */
    private fun styleDataSet(dataSet: LineDataSet) {
        dataSet.setDrawIcons(false)

        // Lines Style
        dataSet.color = rootView!!.resources.getColor(R.color.greenPrimary)
        dataSet.setCircleColor(rootView!!.resources.getColor(R.color.greenDark))
        dataSet.circleRadius = 5.0.toFloat()
        dataSet.setDrawCircleHole(false)
        dataSet.setDrawValues(false) // Do not draw values
    }
}
```

Implementation of BaseViewMvc:

```
abstract class BaseViewMvc {

    var rootView: View? = null
        protected set

    protected val context: Context
        get() = rootView!!.context

    protected fun <T : View> findViewById(id: Int): T {
        return rootView!!.findViewById(id)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Already solved! The problem was the way I defined the ViewMvc. I changed it and now works perfectly:

From:

```
private val marketPriceViewMvcImpl: MarketPriceViewMvcImpl
        get() {
            return MarketPriceViewMvcImpl(layoutInflater, null)
        }
```

to

```
private val mViewMvc: MarketPriceViewMvcImpl by lazy {
        MarketPriceViewMvcImpl(layoutInflater, null, this)
    }
```